# Which Stack Exchange for publications searching related questions (specifically Google Scholar)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which would be the right Stack Exchange to post a question about searching for publications (more specifically about Google Scholar)?

Comment: Can you add more detail about what kind of question it would be?

Comment: the specific question would be "how to use google scholar to search key words in abstracts". Btw, if you know the answer, do not hesitate to answer =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) *may* be your best bet (I'm not sure of this), you may want to see their [faq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) or ask in their [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu) first.

Comment: I saw that they have the tag there (and they dont have the tag in [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/). However the tag google-scholar has been used just 5 times in WebApps